# Apply Thévenin equiv. on this diode problem?

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes, thevenin

I'm wondering if I'm thinking right when wanting to use the Thévenin equiv. on this diode problem?
I'm thinking that in order for me to calculate \$I_D\$ then I have to "open circuit" the diode? 
Am I thinking wrong?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to do. Are you talking about replacing everything **except** the diode with its Thevenin equivalent? When you say "in order to calculate Id" do you mean after creating the Thevenin equivalent or during the process of creating it? If you open circuit the diode, doesn't that mean that Id is 0 by definition?

Comment: The question says determine \$I_D\$

Comment: You could use Thévenin to make a simplified equivalent circuit of \$I_A, V_B, R_1\$ and \$R_2\$. **However** do you really need that? Since the \$V_T\$ of the diode is given we know the voltage across the diode (assuming it is in forward mode). So then why not simply replace the diode with a voltage source, determine the currents and check if that solution would also work if the voltage source was actually a diode.

Comment: You know the current in \$R_2\$ is imposed by \$I_A\$ and the one in \$R_1\$ flows towards \$V_B\$ as 0.7 V is greater than 0.5 V. Calculate \$IR_1\$ and subtract it from \$I_A\$, this is the diode current you want (800 µA).

Comment: Clearly 200 uA has to flow into \$V_B\$'s positive terminal leaving 800 uA to flow into the diode. R2 is irrelevant. Superposition is not required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can solve this problem using different ways.

And yes you are right, in order to calculate the Thevenin equiv. looking from diode terminals, you have to open the diode, calculate the \$R_{th}\$ and \$V_{th}\$ and then put the diode back.

Using nodal analysis to calculate \$V_{th}\$ across diode terminals

$$
\frac{V_B-V_{th}}{R1} +I_A=0
$$
$$
\therefore V_B-V_{th}=-I_AR_1
$$
$$
\therefore V_{th}=V_B+I_AR_1=0.5+0.001\times1000=1.5volts
$$
Then we calculate \$R_{th}\$ By replacing every source with its internal resistance (making current sources open and voltage source close)
$$
R_{th}=1k \Omega
$$

Since \$V_T\$ of the diode equals \$0.7\$

$$
I_D=I_{total}=\frac{1.5-0.7}{1000}=800\mu A
$$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLIT6C.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Please don't give out homework solutions. We expect the OP to show a significant amount of effort and ask a specific question.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I gave him procedures for solving Thevenin equivalent for this circuit.

Comment: No, you gave them the complete answer before they had done any work themselves.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson  Is this site suggests not to answer the questions completely?

Comment: @AbdulrhmanAboghanima thank you for your answer. I just need to ask, Rth, how come it becomes 1kohm?

Comment: @Vetenskap By shorting vlotage sources and opening current sources, then look at the terminals you want to clculate \$R_{th}\$ from , then you will find the \$R_{th}\$ value you want

Comment: @AbdulrhmanAboghanima I opened the current source and closed the voltage source. Then I'm left with R1 and R2 and when I try to calculate the Rth of them I don't get the same answer as you. Am I thinking incorrectly?

Comment: @Vetenskap I added a schematic to my answer. Is that  clear to you now?

Comment: @AbdulrhmanAboghanima I made the same schematic on paper, however I did R1xR2/ (R1+R2), and I get 500 ohm. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106383/discussion-between-abdulrhman-aboghanima-and-vetenskap).

Comment: @AbdulrhmanAboghanima You should learn about the culture of this site, perhaps starting with https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions